# Designing Layout-normal for a lot of densities in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm working on an app in Android and I'm with problems designing layouts for many densities.
I've read the [android's documentation about supporting screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and a lot of blogs and I'm still very confused about the theme.
In my app, I've created the android resources directory according to the documentation. I mean, I have the following layout folders:

- layout-normal/mylayout.xml
- layout-small/mylayout.xml
- layout-large/mylayout.xml
- layout-xlarge/mylayout.xml

The problem is that when I work with the mylayout.xml for the normal screens, this layout doesn't appear good for all densities. For example, the layout is used by two device with normal screen but one of them has a xxhdpi density 640dpX360dp (Samsung s4) and the other device has a mdpi density 480dpX320dp (Sony Xperia ST21a). When I see the results is very amazing the differences between each other and If I work to accomodate one of them, the other (of course) change and is bad.

This is the layout for a normal screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/androidladscape"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
    android:src="@drawable/btnclose"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_marginBottom="37dp"
    android:background="@drawable/downloadsmall"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
    android:text="@string/button_download"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="29dp"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/title_2"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:textColor="#fafdff"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="0.15sp"
    android:fontFamily="oswaldbold.ttf"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/description_2"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView3"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="2sp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:fontFamily="3"
    android:lines="3"
    android:maxLines="3" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the result is:

- for 640x360dp in xxhdpi

[image]

- for 480x320dp in mdpi

[image]

As you can see, I'm using dp and sp as android recommended, but I really don't understand it. The problem begin more bigger if I add a button just under the second paragraph. In the Samsung S4 I can see it but in the Xperia directly doesn't appear.

How can I work with this situation?

Thanks you.
P.S.: I read a lot of questions here but I could not find an answer that can help me.

[UPDATE]

The following image shows what I want in my design for a layout-normal:

[image]

But, when I test it on a Moto G device (Normal screen with xhdpi density 592dpX360dp), I can see the following:

[image]

And, the S4 shows the following:

[image]

If I set one, the other breaks.

This is the layout updated, I'm using default android fonts

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/bgtestlandscape"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
    android:src="@drawable/testclose"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_marginBottom="37dp"
    android:background="@drawable/testdownload"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
    android:text="@string/download"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="29dp"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/title_2"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="0.15sp"
    android:fontFamily="oswaldbold.ttf"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/description_2"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView3"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="2sp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:fontFamily="3"
    android:lines="3"
    android:maxLines="3" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If my answer helped you please consider to upvote or accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

As I can see in your layout - you want text to be left aligned with bottom button and right aligned with top ("cross") button.

You should use `sp` units everywhere for text. Your `Button` uses `dp` units because of that you get different proportions between `TextView` and `Button` widths on different screens.

Remove TextView alignment to start of `ImageButton` and align both TextViews to start and end of Button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/bgtestlandscape"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:src="@drawable/testclose"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginBottom="37dp"
        android:background="@drawable/testdownload"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:text="@string/download"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="29sp"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/title_2"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="0.15sp"
        android:fontFamily="oswaldbold.ttf"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button"
     />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/description_2"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="2sp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:fontFamily="3"
        android:lines="3"
        android:maxLines="3" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**OLD ANSWER**

It seems that Sony Xperia ST21a has Android 4.0 installed. And `android:fontFamily` attribute that you use to set custom font is available since Android 4.1. So on Sony Xperia your text is rendered using default Android font.

To set custom font in Android 4.0 and earlier:

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "oswaldbold.ttf");
text.setTypeface(font);
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using custom font, but I testing using default android font and occurs the same. There is a difference in the positioning of things

Comment: I do not understand what you are not happy with. Both screenshots look the same except font.

Comment: You should text size of first `TextView` in `sp`, not `dp`.

Comment: The positioning of the textviews are different. I updated the question with the design result that I need.

Comment: Also `RelativeLayout` does not need `android:orientation="vertical"`.

Comment: I almost there...I did what @mixel answered and that worked perfectly for the textviews. Now, I have to understand and work hard with the images for all densities. This is making me lose my head :(